# Rebuilding an index, without knowing the index name (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the correct way to rebuild an index of a specific constraint, without knowing the index name, since it might different between environments.
In this case, prefer not knowing the index name (existing condition), and not renaming it first.

ALTER INDEX (select index_name from user_constraints where constraint_name = upper('constraint123')) REBUILD;

I tried casting, string, as is... and getting the following error

ORA-00953: missing or invalid index name

ALTER INDEX (select index_name from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'constraint123') REBUILD

Comment: not like that.  You can't use dynamic sql in DDL.  You would have to use pl/sql and get the index name then use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  However, I would question a design where the same constraint name uses differently named indexes in different environments.

Comment: Like that?

declare
   strIndex NCHAR(20);
begin
   select index_name INTO strIndex from user_constraints where constraint_name = 'constraint123';
   execute immediate 'ALTER INDEX ' || strIndex || 'REBUILD';
end;
/

Comment: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you don't know an object name (table name, column name, etc..) you have to use dynamic SQL, and that requires PL/SQL. Here's how you would do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_rebuild_constraint_index (in_constraint_name IN varchar2)
AS
  var_index_name varchar2(128);
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(index_name)
    INTO var_index_name
    FROM user_constraints
   WHERE constraint_name = in_constraint_name;

  IF var_index_name IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX "'||var_index_name||'" REBUILD';
  END IF;
END;
```

Then simply call it:

```
BEGIN p_rebuild_constraint_index('CONSTRAINT123'); END;
```